# How to paginate roster fetch call on ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd, smack, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-hooks, ejabberd-api

I am running my chat service on ejabberd, but after 4-5 months of no downtime, I have come to use case where it's taking a lot of time in fetching rosters for the users whose roster list is too big. At many places it's mentioned that pagination functionality is not present on ejabberd, but is there any way we can optimise it ?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there is no XMPP specification that define roster pagination. ejabberd does not do anything special in that regard.

What you can look into is XMPP roster versioning (https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0237.html), but this is different from pagination.

Comment: hey mickael, how ejabberd has solved the scalability problems in terms on number of rosters for a user ? What if number of rosters in user's profile is in thousands or lacs ? In such scenarios client will keep waiting till all rosters are fetched, and once this list is fetched how list can be refreshed quickly in case of addition on any roster in the list ? It's creating bad customer experience. Any work around ?

Comment: XMPP is not designed to support rosters with thousands of contacts. It depends on what you want to achieve but you have to design your solution differently.